# OSX El Captian: How can I switch screen without Apple Magic Mouse or Tracking pad

Tags: macos, mac, mouse

I just update my mac to El Captian. I find that maximize button forces applications into full screen mode. I'm ok with this but I cannot switch screen since I don't have a multi-touch device.
Actually I'm bridging my ordinary mouse from another PC (windows) to this mac with Synergy.
How can I switch screen without a multi touch device?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use whatever shortcut keys you would like to define for moving between spaces, in `System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts`. Default should be <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>, but you can change it.

[image]

An alternative method is to define a Hot Corner to toggle Mission Control.

Additionally, note that for most applications, you should be able to hold down <kbd>option</kbd> (perhaps <kbd>alt</kbd> depending on your key mapping), to override the default full screen behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

I made [Mac Mouse Fix](https://mousefix.org).

It lets you remap your Side Buttons to switching between full-screen apps among other neat stuff.

It's also 100% free, it's light on system resources, easy-to-use, and fully open source.

Answer (score 0):

Press F3 to invoke Mission Control, and then select the screen that you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I disabled Function keys to use for macros.. is there any other choices?

Comment: If you swapped the F-key behaviour, then you just use Fn/F-Key to use the 'alternates'

Answer (score 0):

Try SteerMouse (http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/), it's easy to setup and allows you to assign these functions to any button on your mouse.